# I need GoogleService_Info.plist file from existing Firebase project

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-console

I have an android flutter app that I created using Android Studio on a Windows machine. However, now I need to move everything to a Mac iOS machine. This has been a true test of my patients.

I need to get the GoogleServices-Info.plist file for a Firebase project that already exists. I have followed the directions on Firebase but I don't see any download button.

*1. Go to your. Project settings in the Firebase console.*

*2. In the Your apps card, select the bundle ID of the app for which you need a config file.*

This Firebase project already existed so I don't know how to get the file.

Answer (score 2):

1. Click on your existing Firebase project at https://console.firebase.google.com/
2. Select your iOS/Android app, then click on the cog icon to access to the setting page.
3. Click on the Download icon.

You can see the full manipulation here:

[image]

Comment: Great answer!  While this may seem trivial to experienced users, I often still find myself temporarily looking for the right links and your animation makes it crystal clear.

Comment: Thanks for you response. I don't have a download button for the file. I do have a button for a Google-Services.json file. Why do I not see the other button?